# Get array index by Max value?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I found some solutions to get max value of indexes, but how can I get the max value when I have array like this:

```
myArray = [];
myArray[1] = 10;
myArray[2] = 99;

alert(Math.max(myArray));
```

I would like to get index of max value. In this case it would be index 2 of value 99.

The result I get now is `NaN.alert(Math.max(myArray));`

Comment: You need a loop to run trough the array and compare values. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824145/sorting-a-multidimensional-array-in-javascript

Answer (score 4):

**1. If you only want the first instance:**

```
var arrayMaxIndex = function(array) {
  return array.indexOf(Math.max.apply(null, array));
};

console.log(arrayMaxIndex([1,2,7,2])); //outputs 2
```

**2. If you want all occurrences of the max:**

```
function getAllIndexes(arr, val) {
    var indexes = [], i = -1;
    while ((i = arr.indexOf(val, i+1)) != -1){
        indexes.push(i);
    }
    return indexes;
}

var arrayAllMaxIndexes = function(array){
    return getAllIndexes(array, Math.max.apply(null, array));
}

console.log(arrayAllMaxIndexes([1,2,7,2,7])); // outputs [2,4]
```

Everyone does ES6 Updates so here is mine:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3];
const max = Math.max.apply(Math, arr.map((i) => i));
const maxIndex = arr.indexOf(max);
```

Also you can achieve the same thing using `reduce`:

```
const getMax = (arr) => arr.reduce((acc, item) => (item > acc ? item : acc), arr[0]);
```

Comment: A slight variation is `return array.indexOf(Math.max.apply({}, array));`

Comment: The while loop in getAllIndexes runs arr.indexOf over the rest of the array many times.
Here's a simpler for loop the gives the same result but does so more efficiently by only running over the array once:
`for (let i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++) {
  if (array[i] === val) {
   indexes.push(i);
  }
 }`

Comment: Also if you wonder how `Math.max.apply(null, array)` works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24541600/how-does-applymath-arrayname-work-javascript

Comment: How to get the last max occurrence index?

Comment: arr.lastIndexOf(Math.max(...arr))