# sorting 2 dimensional Javascript array

Tags: javascript

Can any one help me in sorting a 2 Dimensional Array

Which will have the data in the following format

```
[2, All are fine]
[4, All is Well]
[1, Welcome Code]
[9, Javascript]

After sorting it should look like 

[2, All are fine]
[4, All is Well]
[9, Javascript]
[1, Welcome Code]
```

Main thing that i am focussing is to sort based on Text not on the ID

Comment: possible duplicate of [sort outer array based on values in inner array, javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793847/sort-outer-array-based-on-values-in-inner-array-javascript)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
ary.sort(function(a, b) { return (a[1] < b[1] ? -1 : (a[1] > b[1] ? 1 : 0)); });
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/tdBWh/ for this example, and [MDC for documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Answer (score 3):

You can use this kind of code :

```
function sortMultiDimensional(a,b)
{
    // for instance, this will sort the array using the second element    
    return ((a[1] < b[1]) ? -1 : ((a[1] > b[1]) ? 1 : 0));
}
```

and then use the sort method :

```
myArray.sort(sortMultiDimensional);
```

Regards,

Max

Comment: @harigm: sorry, i needed to complete my answer (and i did)

Answer (score 2):

```
 ary.sort(function(x,y) { return x[1].localeCompare(y[1]) })
```

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/casyzyb5.aspx