# Store information in object, sort by key + search object later

Tags: javascript, sorting

I'm having a hard time figuring out this.

So, I am making a site where I need to store the horizontal position of elements in a object with the ID as value. Then I need to sort the object by the key. Later I have to loop though the object and find the closest elements (both before and after).

I am struggling with storing the information. I have it like a variabel.

Is it correct to store it like this:

```
myObj.x = tempId;
```

Next, how do I sort the keys? It should sort as a number, not text because I had problem with the sort doing `14, 1500, 800`.

And last, how can I loop the object and maintain access to both key and value? If I do `for (var i in obj)` I loose the key-value.

Comment: You can't sort Object keys, they are not arrays and order is not gauranteed.

Comment: How should I pull this off then? I have no clue how to do this the simplest way. It does not sound very difficult but it's giving me a lot of headache.

Comment: Store the key/values in a multidimensional array and sort by the value. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793847/sort-outer-array-based-on-values-in-inner-array-javascript

Comment: Regarding `for (var i in obj)`: `i` is the key and `obj[i]` will be the value...