# Sorting nested array based on second value in the inner array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am working on a script in which I have to sort arr of arrays based on second element of inner arrays. For example here below I mentioned array:

```
var newInv = [
    [2, "Hair Pin"],
    [3, "Half-Eaten Apple"],
    [67, "Bowling Ball"],
    [7, "Toothpaste"]
];
```

I want to sort this array based on all string values in inner arrays. So result should be:

```
var result = [
    [67, "Bowling Ball"],
    [2, "Hair Pin"],
    [3, "Half-Eaten Apple"],
    [7, "Toothpaste"]
];
```

For this I have written following script:
Is there any other way to do same thing? May be without creating object?

```js
function arraySort(arr) {

  var jsonObj = {};
  var values = [];
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    jsonObj[arr[i][1]] = arr[i][0];

  }
  values = Object.keys(jsonObj).sort();

  for (var j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {
    result.push([jsonObj[values[j]], values[j]]);
  }
  return result;
}

var newInv = [
  [2, "Hair Pin"],
  [3, "Half-Eaten Apple"],
  [67, "Bowling Ball"],
  [7, "Toothpaste"]
];


console.log(arraySort(newInv));
```

Comment: *"without creating json object"* - You haven't created a "JSON object" ([there's no such thing](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)), you've created an "object".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

> The **`sort()`** method sorts the elements of an array *in place* and returns the array. The sort is not necessarily [stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability). The default sort order is according to string Unicode code points.

with [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

> The **`localeCompare()`** method returns a number indicating whether a reference string comes before or after or is the same as the given string in sort order.

```js
var newInv = [[2, "Hair Pin"], [3, "Half-Eaten Apple"], [67, "Bowling Ball"], [7, "Toothpaste"]];
  
newInv.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a[1].localeCompare(b[1]);
});

console.log(newInv);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks for quick solution with wonderful explanation. It's really helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, like this, using `Array`'s [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method:

```
 newInv.sort((a, b) => a[1].localeCompare(b[1]));
```

Here's a snippet:

```js
var newInv = [
    [2, "Hair Pin"],
    [3, "Half-Eaten Apple"],
    [67, "Bowling Ball"],
    [7, "Toothpaste"]
];

newInv.sort((a, b) => a[1].localeCompare(b[1]));

console.log(newInv);
```

Comment: NOTE: This is  ES6 syntax

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of [sort outer array based on values in inner array, javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793847/sort-outer-array-based-on-values-in-inner-array-javascript)
here you will find several answers, like my own

```
var arr = [.....]
arr.sort((function(index){
    return function(a, b){
        return (a[index] === b[index] ? 0 : (a[index] < b[index] ? -1 : 1));
    };
})(2)); // 2 is the index
```

This sorts on index 2