# Error when I try to combine string

Tags: javascript, string

I have error in my script when I'm using following line

```
var s = "{group:'" + $group + 
        "',result: '" + $result + 
        "',groupName: '" + $groupName + "'}";
```

For following example values:

```
group = ""
result = "sfsfs fsfsf " 
groupName = "grupa1"
```

Is here any mistake?

Best regards.

Comment: And the error is ... ???

Comment: Works for me if I declare the variables.

Comment: Script doesn't run with this line... I don't know debuger to javascript

Comment: without more context (for instance the values of your variables) nobody can answer this.

Comment: group = ""; result = "sfsfs fsfsf ", groupName = "grupa1"

Comment: isn't it $('something')?

Comment: for a debugger, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/103155/javascript-debugger

Comment: @cadi2108 - I'm afraid this isn't enough. I didn't try, but javascript string concatenation (`+`) should work, and if you will try to define the variables and run the script, it will work. By the way: what are you doing with `s`? Are you trying to parse it as JSON? From javascript!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the dollar sign before the variable. Try this

```
var s = "{group:'" + group + 
    "',result: '" + result + 
    "',groupName: '" + groupName + "'}";
```

Comment: Unless the dollar sign is part of the variable name, in which case they *are* needed.

Comment: Hi, nice guess! The OP did say `group = ""`, and `$group`.

Comment: @Guffa the edit to the question shows it isn't

Answer (score 1):

*[Reposted answer, as the answer was converted to a comment while I was editing it.]*

There is no error in that code.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/UCmtF/

```
var $group = "", $result = "sfsfs fsfsf ", $groupName = "grupa1";

var s = "{group:'" + $group +
        "',result: '" + $result +
        "',groupName: '" + $groupName + "'}";

alert(s);
```

Shows:

```
{group:'',result: 'sfsfs fsfsf ',groupName: 'grupa1'}
```

Comment: Sorry about that.  You can flag a deleted post to be undeleted once it's edited.  Your original answer really shouldn't have even been flagged inside the edit grace period.  This happens so rarely that mods seldom look for it.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: I tried to undelete the answer, but I got a message that it wasn't possible as it was conveted to a comment.

Comment: That's because a moderator deleted it, so only a mod can undelete it.  You could have flagged again, explaining that you were in the process of editing when it was deleted, to get it undeleted.  Reposting the answer is fine, I just wanted you to know in the unlikely event that this happens again.

Answer (score 0):

Is this JavaScript or PHP? If PHP, the concat operator is . and not +. If JS, I can't find any error.

Answer (score 0):

You want concat php string to javascript. see my code

```
var s = "{group:' <?php echo $group; ?> ',result:' <?php echo $result; ?> ',groupName:' <?php echo $groupName; ?> '}";
```